# jquery gauge plugin not working inside ng-repeat angular 1

Tags: jquery, angularjs

**index.html**

```
   <div class="js-gauge--1">
   </div>
```

**jquery.js**

```
$('.js-gauge--1').kumaGauge({
    value : Math.floor((Math.random() * 99) + 1)
  }); 
  var update = setInterval(function() {
    var newVal = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99) + 1);
    $('.js-gauge--1').kumaGauge('update',{
      value : newVal
    });   
  }, 1000);

 **Its not working:**

 <div class="number" ng-repeat="thing in things">
 <div class="js-gauge--1">
   </div>
   </div>

  **its working:**

 <div class="js-gauge--1">
   </div>
   <div class="number" ng-repeat="thing in things"
    <p>test</p>
   </div>
```

i could not found why its happen?? 
help me for this issue!

jquery its running out of ng-repeat but its not running inside the ng-repeat

I am using "Creating-Animated-Gauges-Using-jQuery-Raphael-js-kumaGauge" this plugin for gauge chart.